# Using models in a scrape to access data

Tags: python, django

I'm using Python (w/ Django) with BeautifulSoup to scrape a number of websites.  I want to use a list of websites in a DB I have set up with my Django App to loop through some websites and grab some information

I have a "Webpages" file with "models.py".  This all works and I have set up a site simply to show the list of webpages in the DB

I have then added a "Scrape.py" file and can successfully do a simple scrape by going to Git Bash and running "py scrape.py"

However, I want to loop through the websites in my DB.  To do so I thought I would need to do this first and then use it to fetch data

```
from .webpages.models import Webpage
```

But before I add any further code I get the error "ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package"

I have also tried

```
from webpages.models import Webpage
```

But then I get the error "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'webpages'"

I have searched online and found [this guide](https://napuzba.com/a/import-error-relative-no-parent), and followed but no such luck.  As guide it asks you to place the following code in the file

```
 print('__file__={0:<35} | __name__={1:<20} | __package__={2:<20}'.format(__file__,__name__,str(__package__)))
```

... and it becomes clear what the issue is -  when I run the script there are large blanks where there should be information about the package the module belongs.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get that information to register

My files are structured as such

```
 project
 ├── webpages
     ├── models.py
 └── scrapes
     ├── scrape.py
```

I'm trying to run the above through Git Bash, but also added -m but still no luck

Comment: Can you simplify your post to focus on a single issue?

Comment: It is only a single issue - just not great at asking the question  I guess!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because you do not initialize Django before using models in you script. Best way to do it - use django commands. Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/#module-django.core.management

Comment: Thanks - the link taught me a lot, and now have it working :)